# Quid est opus quod Cicerō in Dē senectūte § 75 prōfert?

Tags: cicero

In opere Cicerōnis *Dē senectūte* ipse dīxit: «quod scrīpsī in Orīginibus» (§ 75). Quid est hoc opus? Quid est nōmen rēctum sibī anglicum? In pāginā interrētis [*Lacus Curtius*](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Cicero/Cato_Maior_de_Senectute/text*.html) nōmen operis *Orīgō* in linguam anglicam *Antiquities* versum ’st. In pāginā interrētis [*The Latin Library*](https://thelatinlibrary.com/cic.html) opus hujus nōminis invenīre nōn possum. Ubī id legere possum? Num, dīs caelīs, opus aeōnibus nōn dēperitum ’st?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In opere Cicerōnis Dē senectūte ipse dīxit: «quod scrīpsī in Orīginibus»

You have to be careful here, as, yes, this is Cicero's *De Senectute*, but the speaker in the text is Cato the Elder. So it is referring not to any work that Cicero wrote, but Cato. With that knowledge, you can check PHI, which lists Cato's [*Origines*](https://latin.packhum.org/author/22) among his works.

As far as the name goes, scholars typically just the Latin. Astin's [landmark study](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cato_the_Censor/RZ01czEqfSQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cato+origines&pg=PA223&printsec=frontcover) on Cato uses *Origines* throughout, as does Tim Cornell's monograph [*Cato's* Origines *and the Non-Roman Historical Tradition about Ancient Italy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cato_s_Origines_and_the_Non_Roman_Histor/oxfgjgEACAAJ?hl=en). Likewise, in the *Cambridge Companion to the Roman Historians*, the English translation of Gotter's article is "Cato's *Origines*: the historian and his enemies." You chiefly see *Antiquities* or something like it in 19th century literature.

Using *Origines* in English is so pervasive and *Antiquities* is so old-fashioned that I didn't even consider mentioning the latter as an option when I wrote up an article on [Cato](https://ephor.us/epitome/cato-the-elder/):

> No other complete works of Cato survive, though a good portion of his *Origines* and a couple speeches survive in part from quotations.

Answer (score 7):

Nota bene nomen istius operis re vera esse « Cato Maior de Senectute »! Nam etsi a Cicerone scriptum est, hic praeclarus scriptor [Catonem Maiorem](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Porcius_Cato_maior) ipsum induxit disputantem, quia neminem existimabat de senectute maiore auctoritate loqui quam eum et, ut postea scripsit in opere c.n. [« Laelius de Amicitia »](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/amic.shtml) (eodem modo scilicet scriptum), quia sermo hominibus veteribus attributus ei « plus nescio quo pacto habere gravitatis » videretur. Effectus fuit talis ut Cicero sua verba ipse legens putaverit Catonem secum loqui, ut dixit eodem loco.

Forma operis igitur est dialogi inter C. Laelium Sapientem, P. Cornelium Scipionem, M. Porcium Catonem. In capitulo de quo mentionem fecisti, Catonem loquentem fecit Cicero. Cum igitur de « Originibus » sermo est, id ad [Origines](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origines) Catonis ipsius refert. Quod opus, tristissimum dictu, nobis non traditum est.

Answer (score 5):

A note in my text of *De Senectute* (edited by Shuckburgh) says "for Cato's *Origines* see Introduction. Cicero quotes this sentence from the fourth book of the *Origines* again in *Tusc.* 1, 42, 101."

In this introduction is a brief description of some of Cato's works, including:

> The *Origines* (§38). Cato seems to have begun this work with the idea of treating only on early Roman history, and the origin of the Roman state and of the various neighboring towns, -- a kind of compendium of local antiquities. But his plan gradually extended to the writing of the history of Rome down to his own day, (the book is thus sometimes spoken of as *Annales*), and he added to it up to the last days of his life. It has all perished with the exception of a few insignificant fragments; but it was much used by subsequent writers, though Cicero says it was thin and dry (*exilis* -- *De Legg.* 1, 2, 6). The first book told the story of the Kings; the second and third, the origins of the Italian *civitates*; the fourth, the First Punic War; the fifth, the Second Punic War; the sixth and seventh, the history of Rome from the end of that war to the last days of Cato's life.

Note that this refers to §38 (of *De Senectute*) where the *Origines* is mentioned again.